# How to count downloads of an image

Tags: wordpress, analytics

I am an Amazon author, who has cunningly inserted a 1 pixel x 1 pixel image onto the sales page of his book.  My intent is to track how many times that image is viewed, thus learning how many people are visiting said page.

So far, so good, but: how do I count the downloads of the image?  I have spent all afternoon Googling this, but have been unable to find a way to do it in Wordpress or Google Analytics.

The image is stored in the "Media Library" of my site, which is hosted on WP Engine.  I did investigate hosting the image on Flickr instead, but Flickr doesn't seem to like me hotlinking images.  I am open to hosting the image somewhere else that will allow me to see how many times it is viewed.

If anybody can point me in the right direction, I'll be very grateful.

Thanks,

-Charlie.

Comment: You can create a custom app that counts the no. of times the image is requested. The no. of times image is requested in the total no. of times it is viewed.

Comment: Hi Charlie, you may like to use dedicated tracking solution which works just like that but provides you all visitors states , how many visited, from which country etc..called web stats, you might look at Google Analytics, https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/ there are many other free alternatives. You just include small JS code instead of img, and it tracks all info.